# Unable to send Post request using RestAssured

Tags: json, groovy, rest-assured

I am getting below error when sending Post request using RestAssured.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static io.restassured.internal.http.URIBuilder.encode() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [prweb, UTF-8]
Possible solutions: hashCode()
```

Below is the line in which the error is getting thrown

```
request.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username" + ":" + "password").getBytes()));
request.post(path);
```

Can someone please suggest. Thanks..

Comment: Why not just use the below ?

given().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password"), which version of rest assured are you using ? also post the complete code

Comment: I am using rest-assured-3.3.0.jar. The same code is working in a different system.

Comment: Ahh, This seems to be more of a dependency issue in that case, Are you using maven/gradle or importing the libs manually ? Also try adding this
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.5.6

Comment: I am using Maven. groovy-all-3.0.0-alpha-1.jar is already added.

Comment: Try downgrading it to 2.5.6, 3.0.0 is an alpha build, I'm running out of options as well, so if it doesn't work probably let's wait for someone else to pick this up

Comment: I will try with 2.5.6. Thanks.